# Best way to make start and end segments of an *.mp3 have no sound?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, debian

I know there are various linux packages that allow you to crop a portion of a song.  For example to crop a 30 second portion of a 2 minute song mysong.mp3 starting at the 1 minute mark

```
ffmpeg -ss 60 -t 30 -acodec copy -i mysong.mp3 30secondportion.mp3
```

How can I create a new .mp3 where the first 60 seconds of this song have no sound, the following 30 seconds have sound, and the last 30 seconds have no sound?

The resulting .mp3 should be 2 minutes in length.

I'm using ubuntu 10.04

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1052782)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about audio processing, and would be a better fit for http://avp.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://billposer.org/Linguistics/Computation/SoxTutorial.html):

- Using `Sox` to Extract Subparts of a File
- Using `Sox` to Create Silence
- Using `Sox` to Concatenate Files